# PHP with paypal validation

Tags: php, validation, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am only just starting to get to grips with PHP, so please forgive me if I have missed something obvious. My problem is this:

I have a script that validates when a payment has been made, when a payment has been made it includes the following:

```
include 'newtest/generate.php';
```

"generate.php" creates a random single use URL, finds the user that is logged in and emails the link to them. It finds the users email like this:

```
include 'includes/common.inc.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . $DBPrefix . "users WHERE id = " . $user->user_data['id'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
$USER = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$usermail = $USER['email'];
```

If I run generate.php via my browser, everything works fine.. it picks up the logged in user details and sends the link.

However, when a paypal payment is made it won't. I thought this might be something wrong with paypal validation. But its not, if I set

```
$usermail = 'me@mydomain.com';
```

and then make a test payment, everything works fine. So basically, why won't my script pick up on the users email when paypal sends the request?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to put an absolute path on the include file. If that file contents some data like $DBPrefix, the query couldn't be completed. You can call PHP's function error_log to see the query.

Comment: Thanks for the input!
I tried using the absolute path to the include file. Still nothing...

Comment: I've even mass replaced all the variables for the includes path in common.inc.php with the full path... I'm pulling my hair out here.